# PHP different behavior when called between browser and curl

Tags: php, curl, memory-leaks

I have a strange behavior and I hope that someone here can help me.
I make the same call once with a browser and once with curl.

Example

`browser: https://www.myurl.com/index.php?foo=bar`

`curl:    curl https://www.myurl.com/index.php?foo=bar`

If I call the url with the browser (no matter which), then everything works as expected. My memory overflows when I call the url with curl.

Code snippet:

```
private function doSomething()
{
    $this->doSomeLog('Start process');
    foreach ($foo as $bar) {
        $this->doLogMemory('Memory usage: ' . memory_get_usage());
        $this->callMethodA();
        $this->callMethodB();
        // some more code
    }
}

// Output browser (memory stays at the same level):
>Start process
>Memory usage: 25384948
>Memory usage: 25386731
>Memory usage: 25396326
>Memory usage: 25396326

// Output curl (memory grows steadily):
>Start process
>Memory usage: 25384948
>Memory usage: 162495865
>Memory usage: 236915437
>Memory usage: 426158496
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be and how to avoid/fix it?

Comment: The only difference is in the HTTP headers. Find out which one, or trace your app to find the leak. That "memory stays when called from browser" is actually irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. It was an entry in php.ini.
zend.assertions had an entry of 1. After I set the value to -1, the memory didn't increase any further.

Comment: .. that suggest you're using a lot of RAM in assert() code :o that's not normal.